# Shell Script does not send email from Cron job

Tags: shell-script, cron

I have a shell script which sends email when the disk is more than 80% full; when I run the script as `sh -x script.sh` or `./script.sh` I get an email but when I keep the script in cronjob I do not get any email.

The script has execute permissions (755).

When I type `mail` I can see the cronjob has ran at that time, but there is no email sent.

Comment: HINT:  Set the PATH variable explicitly in your script and make sure it is exported.

Comment: @mdpc , I am new to linux, shell scripting. Do I need to add the line export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/dir1
 where /path/to/dir is the script.sh path ?

Comment: When I run $PATH in my server I can see some values already set, If I add this PATH variable in my script (which points to my script.sh path) will it overwrite the previous values ?

Comment: @mdpc I moved the shell script to one of the directories as listed in the $PATH, now the script runs fine from crontab, thank you for the hint

Comment: @YRVK.  Please Choose "Answer my own Question" below your name, as this is a duplicate and I'm voting as such

Answer (score 0):

You can do 2 things.

1. Put the full path in for sendmail. `/usr/sbin/sendmail` for example.
2. Put the following commands at the beginning of you crontab:

`SHELL=/bin/bash
 PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`